# Продолжает ли работать DialogFragment после вызова dismiss()?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть диалоговый фрагмент, мне нужно выполнить часть кода, после его закрытия (после того, как он пропадет с экрана). Будет ли выполняться код, после вызова метода `dismiss()`?

Comment: код выполнится, но некоторые методы, например `getActivity()` могут начать возвращать `null`

Comment: @metalurgus, а если предварительно вызвать `mContext = (MyActivity) getActivity()`, все будет работать?

Comment: для чего Вам выполнять этот код после закрытия диалога? Если этот код связан с активностью, то перенесите его в саму активность

Comment: @georgehardcore, да он и так в активности... А вот метод, вызывающий его, должен выполниться после закрытия диалога!

Comment: Вы опять там что то адское костылите? Пишите о проблеме - "как выполнить метод после закрытия диалога", а не о том, как вы эту проблему пытаетесь неправильно решить. После `dismiss()` никакого кода выполнять не рекомендуется, так как его выполнение под большим вопросом.

Comment: А если действительно выполнить этот код перед dismiss()?

Comment: @georgehardcore, видимо, это уже не принципиально... Что за, что до правильно не работает :).

Comment: @pavlofff, я добавляю в `RecyclerView` новый пункт (в диалоговом окне поучаю текст и передаю его в метод активности), но пункт добавляется до того, как уберется клавиатура (то есть, никакой плавности и выглядит не очень), но как я не пытаюсь, клавиатура не хочет исчезать до того, как добавится пункт! Пробовал вызывать код после `dismiss()`, вставлять `wait` после вызова и вставлять `wait` до обновления — ничего не работает! Клавиатура убирается только после выполнения `wait` и, соответственно, закрывая анимацию добавления! Обновляю пункт через `mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mList.size() - 1);`

Comment: @metalurgus, закиньте в ответ. Но у меня метод `getActivity` работает исправно, как ни странно!

Comment: исправьте сам вопрос, а не задавайте в комментарии практически новый. И код, как вы добавляете пункт

Comment: @pavlofff, а есть смысл? Разве я попробовал не все более-менее адекватные варианты?

Comment: Ну раз смысла нет, предлагаю вопрос вовсе удалить :) Я не вижу никаких вариантов решения, не то, что адекватных. Из вашего комментария можно только понять, что все делается не так, как это пытаетесь сделать вы.

Comment: @pavlofff, но на этот же вопрос я ответ получил! :) Пусть metalurgus закинет ответ. Но, если я что-то делаю не так, тогда лучше меня поправят! Пора уже уходить от плохого хода и искать правильные варианты решения проблем...

Comment: Ваша проблема - не скрывается клавиатура при добавлении пунктов в список через диалог. Вы задаете вопрос - как выполнять код после `dismiss()`. Ответ на этот вопрос не решит вашу действительную проблему. Задавайте вопросы по проблемам и код как вы ее получаете. Если не знаете пути решения, не пытайтесь искать неверные решения и тем более задавать по ним вопросы, которые имеют нулевую ценность для сообщества. Я уже устал это повторять.

Comment: @pavlofff, вопрос по проблеме я задам, но почему "нулевую ценность для сообщества"? Моя проблема будет у нескольких (десятков, сотен, тысяч или тд.) людей, а вот такой вопрос может возникнуть без отношения к моей проблеме, ведь верно?

Answer (score 1):

Есть специальный метод `onDismiss`, который декларируется в `onDismissListener` - заимплементируйте этот интерфейс и выполняйте код в нем - и будет вам счастье.

**Update**

Только не забудьте добавить в диалоге `setOnDismissListener()`